# how to add subviews in a 'for' loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm simply trying to add a UIView for every object in an array without displaying more than 3 on screen but the views aren't next to each other. There is a big gap (one view width) between each view. Here's what I've got;

```
int numberOfUsersOnScreen;

if (array.count < 3) {
    numberOfViewsOnScreen = array.count;
}else{
    numberOfUsersOnScreen = 3;
}

double width = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width/numberOfViewsOnScreen);
CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 1200);
[self.usersScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width*array.count, 0)];

for (int i = 0; i < users.count; i++) {  
       r.origin.x = width * i;
       UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initFrame:r];
       [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
}
```

[image: The Orange is the scrollView underneath]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
int xPosition = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < users.count; i++) {  
   UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, 0, width, 1200)];
   [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
   xPosition += width;
}
```

Comment: thanks but still nothing... when I changed r.origin.x = width * i; to r.origin.x = width * i/2; it seems to work but then later in the code when I add a subview to one of the new views it displays half to the left.

Comment: Try setting the backgroundColor on your view to green and it will show you the true width of your view. Also you can Use NSLog to display both the width and the xPosition of each view to make sure the numbers are right.

Comment: I've done that, the green spans the whole scrollView. also the touch events that I've set up for each view act as if the gaps are views. I don't know if thats useful?

Comment: If the green spans the whole subview then your scrollview subviews are behaving as you wanted. There are no gaps. I think your problem may be in the subview of your view. Double check the orange that your adding to each view.

Comment: Sorry I've Worked it out. The gaps between the view aren't blank, their my custom view classes not displaying properly. It's a problem in drawRect;.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width*array.count, 0)];
```

It should be

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width*array.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.count; i++) {  
   r.origin.x = width * i;
   UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initFrame:r];
   [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
}
```

In this way you have also a memory leak on view(s) object

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.count; i++) {  
   r.origin.x = width * i;
   UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initFrame:r];
   [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
   [view release]; 
}
```

Comment: I'm writing in iOS 5. This is cleaned up with ARC. Thanks anyway.